# ¿Cómo migrar de la arquitectura MVC a la arquitectura ADR en PHP puro sin ningún framework?

Tags: php

Tengo una API en PHP escrita según la arquitectura MVC (Model-View-Controller).

En mi caso el Controlador es mi archivo `index.php` que recibe todas las peticiones y las va despachando.

Según he leído la arquitectura MVC no es la más adecuada para aplicaciones web, porque no respeta el principio de responsabilidad única y otros.

Estuve revisando la [arquitectura ADR (Action-Domain-Responder)](https://github.com/pmjones/adr), creada hace unos años por Paul M. Jones, la cual es parecida a MVC y que considero factible para mi contexto, el problema es que no encuentro cómo implementarla.

En Github hay un [código de ejemplo](https://github.com/pmjones/adr-example) creado por el mismo Paul M. Jones, y hay otros ejemplos, como [este](https://github.com/n1215/simple-adr) o [este](https://github.com/tbreuss/adroit), pero basados en frameworks o con código que no logro comprender del todo. En la red hay algunos tutoriales, pero basados en frameworks, nada en PHP puro.

Mi problema en concreto es ¿cómo implementar la arquitectura ADR en PHP puro? ¿Cómo conecto los elementos en contextos como:

- `https:www.miapi/unEndpoint/1`
- `https:www.miapi/otroEndpoint/list`

...etc.

Hasta ahora, como decía al principio, mi `index.php` hace de controlador. ¿Cómo sería en la arquitectura ADR? ¿`index.php` haría de Action, sí, no? **¿cómo se conectan entre sí los elementos?**

Este es un ejemplo simple de mi `index.php` en mi actual estructura MVC:

```
require 'view/vista.php';
$isCorrect=TRUE;

#Obtengo lo que se solicita por URL
if (isset($_GET['PATH_INFO']))
{
    $peticion = explode('/', $_GET['PATH_INFO']);
    $endPoint = $peticion[0];
    $mData=$peticion[1];
    #Controlar endPoints no válidos
    $allowed = array('unEndpoint','otroEndpoint', 'etc',);
}
else
{
    $isCorrect=FALSE;
}

// Comprobar si existe el recurso
if (!in_array($endPoint, $allowed)) 
{
    $isCorrect=FALSE;
}
if (!$isCorrect) 
{
    #Mando a la vista un error
}
else
{
    $metodo = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
    switch ($metodo) 
    {
        case 'get':
            switch ($endPoint) 
            {
                case 'unEndpoint':
                    require 'modelos/unEndpoint.php';
                    $mEndPoint=new UnEndPoint($mData);
                    $vista->imprimir($mEndPoint->getData());
                    break;
        #Siguen los case y el resto ...
```

Comment: Hay una guía específica para [migrar de MVC a ADR](https://github.com/pmjones/adr/blob/master/REFACTORING.md)

Comment: @Triby gracias por el enlace, me parece que ahí encontraré el modo de proceder. Lo revisaré detenidamente y cuando tenga noticias informo. Saludos.

Comment: Otro más, un poco más claro el punto de entrada y [en español](https://diego.com.es/patrones-de-diseno-en-php#ActionDomainResponderPattern)

Comment: Acabo de aprender algo nuevo.